# java.util.Map.contains() method call in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, el

Is there a way to call java.util.Map.contains()  method in JSP where the Map is a property of a bean.

Comment: Since this method does not exist, do you mean `containsKey` or `containsValue`?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for containsValue()method and I am trying to use EL in JSP.Sorry, I should have made it clearer in my question.

Comment: In future JSP EL questions, just tag as such with `[jsp][el]`. I've replaced `[jsp-tags]` by `[el]`. JSP tags like JSTL should really not to be confused with EL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
${fooBean.fooMap.containsValue("baz")}
```

The above will work in JSP 2.2 or better. If you're using a pre-JSP 2.2 container (e.g. Java EE 5) then an EL function is probably the better solution.

Static Java method:

```
package contains;
import java.util.Map;
public class Maps {
    public static boolean containsValue(Map<?, ?> map, Object value) {
        return map.containsValue(value);
    }
}
```

The file `WEB-INF/tlds/maps.tld`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib version="2.1"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd">
  <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
  <short-name>maps</short-name>
  <uri>/WEB-INF/tlds/maps</uri>
   <function>
    <description>Returns true if the value is contained</description>
    <name>containsValue</name>
    <function-class>contains.Maps</function-class>
    <function-signature>
      boolean containsValue(java.util.Map, java.lang.Object)
    </function-signature>
  </function>
</taglib>
```

Usage:

```
<%@taglib prefix="maps" uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/maps" %>
...
${maps:containsValue(fooBean.fooMap, "baz")}
```

Answer (score 8):

I'll assume that you're talking about using EL in JSP the right way and thus not the old fashioned *scriptlets*, otherwise the answer is extremely obvious like as given by AlexR.

You can use the `empty` keyword to test for the presence of a non-null and non-empty value associated with a key.

```xml
<c:if test="${not empty bean.map['somekey']}">
    Map contains a non-null/non-empty value on key "somekey".
</c:if>
```

If you really need to invoke the map's `containsKey()` or `containsValue()` methods, then you need to ensure that you're running a Servlet 3.0 compatible container like Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, JBoss AS 6, etc and that your `web.xml` is declared conform Servlet 3.0. This way you can utilize a new EL 2.2 feature: invoking non-getter methods with arguments.

```xml
<c:if test="${bean.map.containsKey('somekey')}">
    Map contains key "somekey".
</c:if>
<c:if test="${bean.map.containsValue('somevalue')}">
    Map contains value "somevalue".
</c:if>
```

Comment: `${not empty bean.map.somekey}` also works, as long as 'somekey' does not contain a special character (like dots).

Comment: Is there a way to test for values (containsValue() method) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use scriptlet code:

```
<%= yourBean.getMapProperty().contains() %>
```

It's not pretty, but it should work. There may also be some tag libraries available that do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Since JSP is just a java you can call what you want. Just try it.